# Sugarcrm dashlet All Opportunity by lead source not syncing/fetching data

Tags: charts, sugarcrm, dashlet

Hey every One I am facing issue that I add 20 opportunities in sugarcrm and then add dashlet of **All Opportunities by Lead Source** and now i want to populate this chart. according to sugar document it automatically sync data from sugar databsae and Refresh itself after an interval of time. But its not working. How can I fix it or use any other dashlet...

Comment: have you set auto-refresh interval for dashboard? Something like this: $sugar_config['dashlet_auto_refresh_min'] = '30';

Comment: yes i set it to 1 mint

Comment: but its have to sink existing data when i add dash lets

Comment: Which version of SugarCRM you are using and share the log file details.